# How to access method in other file in same project in Memberdata attribute in xunit

Tags: c#-4.0, xunit.net

I have written a test case for a method using Memberdata attribute of xunit. I am able to run the test case successfully, but when I try to use the method from some other file in Memberdata attribute I get the following error:

> Message: Specified method is not supported.

Please let me know how to resolve the issue.

Here is my sample test case. The method XXX is in other file and public access specifier is used for the method.

```
[Theory]
[MemberData("XXX")]
public async void TestSample(string yyy)
{
    var zzz= await CreateSample("bbb", "kkk");
    Assert.NotEmpty(zzz);
}
```

Comment: 'XXX' should be of type ```static IEnumerable<object[]>```, is this the case? please complete the example

Comment: yes. Method XXX is as follows.   public static IEnumerable<object[]> XXX()
{// code...}